# Input file to BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

i've been having trouble trying to implement an input file to my binary search tree and output. I will write my code below, but i dont know where to add the Input file. also in my code i have 4 options, i dont need those. Also i dont know how to use the getopt option, i havent understood that concept yet. and how do i free the memory after the traversal is done to the output file?

---

```
    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct BST {
       int data;
       struct BST *lchild, *rchild;
    } node;

    void insert(node *, node *);
    void inorder(node *);
    void preorder(node *);
    void postorder(node *);
    node *search(node *, int, node **);

    int main() {
       int choice;
       char ans = 'N';
       int key;
       node *new_node, *root, *tmp, *parent;
       node *get_node();
       root = NULL;
       //clrscr();

       printf("\nProgram For Binary Search Tree ");
       do {
          printf("\n1.Create");
          printf("\n2.Search");
          printf("\n3.Recursive Traversals");
          printf("\n4.Exit");
          printf("\nEnter your choice :");
          scanf("%d", &choice);

          switch (choice) {
          case 1:
             do {
                new_node = get_node();
                printf("\nEnter The Element ");
                scanf("%d", &new_node->data);

                if (root == NULL) /* Tree is not Created */
                   root = new_node;
                else
                   insert(root, new_node);

                printf("\nWant To enter More Elements?(y/n)");
               // ans = getch();
             } while (ans == 'y');
             break;

          case 2:
             printf("\nEnter Element to be searched :");
             scanf("%d", &key);

             tmp = search(root, key, &parent);
             printf("\nParent of node %d is %d", tmp->data, parent->data);
             break;

          case 3:
             if (root == NULL)
                printf("Tree Is Not Created");
             else {
                printf("\nThe Inorder display : ");
                inorder(root);
                printf("\nThe Preorder display : ");
                preorder(root);
                printf("\nThe Postorder display : ");
                postorder(root);
             }
             break;
          }
       } while (choice != 4);

    }

    /*
     Get new Node
     */
    node *get_node() {
       node *temp;
       temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
       temp->lchild = NULL;
       temp->rchild = NULL;
       return temp;
    }
    /*
     This function is for creating a binary search tree
     */
    void insert(node *root, node *new_node) {
       if (new_node->data < root->data) {
          if (root->lchild == NULL)
             root->lchild = new_node;
          else
             insert(root->lchild, new_node);
       }

       if (new_node->data > root->data) {
          if (root->rchild == NULL)
             root->rchild = new_node;
          else
             insert(root->rchild, new_node);
       }
    }
    /*
     This function is for searching the node from
     binary Search Tree
     */
    node *search(node *root, int key, node **parent) {
       node *temp;
       temp = root;
       while (temp != NULL) {
          if (temp->data == key) {
             printf("\nThe %d Element is Present", temp->data);
             return temp;
          }
          *parent = temp;

          if (temp->data > key)
             temp = temp->lchild;
          else
             temp = temp->rchild;
       }
       return NULL;
    }
    /*
     This function displays the tree in inorder fashion
     */
    void inorder(node *temp) {
       if (temp != NULL) {
          inorder(temp->lchild);
          printf("%d", temp->data);
          inorder(temp->rchild);
       }
    }
    /*
     This function displays the tree in preorder fashion
     */
    void preorder(node *temp) {
       if (temp != NULL) {
          printf("%d", temp->data);
          preorder(temp->lchild);
          preorder(temp->rchild);
       }
    }

    /*
     This function displays the tree in postorder fashion
     */
    void postorder(node *temp) {
       if (temp != NULL) {
          postorder(temp->lchild);
          postorder(temp->rchild);
          printf("%d", temp->data);
       }
    }
```

Comment: "i dont know where to add the Input file". Just get rid of the "Create" option and do the input processing before entering the options loop. "i dont know how to use the `getopt` option". Have you read the [getopt man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)? If so, what specifically don't you understand? And you haven't even said what you want to use `getopt` for. "how do i free the memory after the traversal is done to the output file". Call `free`? Please make your questions clearer.

Comment: okay well would this work?

void getFile () {
   struct recordNode node;
   struct recordNode *tree;

   FILE* fpin;
   FILE* fpout;

   char line_buffer[lineSize]; /* BUFSIZ is defined if you include stdio.h */
   int counter = 0;
   fpin=fopen("testData.txt", "r");

   if (fpin == NULL ) exit(0);
        counter = 0;
    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), fpin)) { 
               counter++;
               if (counter != 1) {
               sscanf(line_buffer, "%[^','],%s"), node;
               tree = addRecord(tree, node); 

               }

    }
        getchar();